# Exactly once from Kafka source in Apache Beam

Tags: apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Is it possible to do exactly-once processing using a Kafka source, with `KafkaIO` in Beam? There is a flag that can be set called `AUTO_COMMIT`, but it seems that it commits back to Kafka straight after the consumer processed the data, rather than after the pipeline completed processing the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Beam runners like Dataflow and Flink store the processed offsets in internal state, so it is not related to 'AUTO_COMMIT' in Kafka Consumer config. The internal state stored is check-pointed atomically with processing (actual details depends on the runner).

There some more options to achieve end-to-end exactly-once semantics (from source to Beam application to sink). KafkaIO source provides an option to read only committed records, and also supports an exactly-once sink.

Some pipelines do set 'AUTO_COMMIT', mainly so that when a pipeline is restarted from scratch (as opposed to [updated](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/updating-a-pipeline), which preserves internal state), it resumes roughly around there the old pipeline left of. As you mentioned, this does not have processing guarantees.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You mentioned that `KafkaIO source provides an option to read only committed records`. A bit more info on how that can be achieved would be useful.

Comment: See 'withReadCommitted()' : https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.java#L184